# problema con pop

Tags: c++

hola tengo un problema  mi programa no hace pop_back y pop_front.
Un entero N seguido de las N operaciones a realizar sobre búsqueda.
como
AGREGA_IZQ,
AGREGA_DER,
QUITA_IZQ y
AGREGA_DER

`char busqueda[10];` y "valor" es el numero que se ingresa .

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {

    std::cin >> busqueda >> valor;

    if (strcmp(busqueda, "AGREGA_IZQ") == 1) {

        cambios.push_front(valor);
    }
    else if (strcmp(busqueda, "AGREGA_DER") == 1) {
        cambios.push_back(valor);
    }

    else if (strcmp(busqueda, "QUITA_IZQ") == 1) {

        cambios.pop_front();
    }

    else if (strcmp(busqueda, "QUITA_DER") == 1) {

        cambios.pop_back();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

La función `strcmp` devuelve tres valores diferentes:

- Un valor menor a cero cuando una cadena es lexicográficamente previa a la otra.
- Cero cuando ambas cadenas son iguales.
- Un valor mayor a cero cuando una cadena es lexicográficamente posterior a la otra.

En C++ un valor entero se puede convertir implícitamente a una expresión booleana siguiendo estas normas:

- Un valor igual a cero es `falso`.
- Cualquier cosa que no sea cero es `verdadero`.

Por lo tanto, entras en cualquiera de tus `if` si las cadenas que comparas son diferentes. Si quieres entrar cuando son iguales, deberías comprobar que el retorno es `0`:

```
if (strcmp(busqueda, "AGREGA_IZQ") == 0) {
    cambios.push_front(valor);
}
else if (strcmp(busqueda, "AGREGA_DER") == 0) {
    cambios.push_back(valor);
}
else if (strcmp(busqueda, "QUITA_IZQ") == 0) {
    cambios.pop_front();
}
else if (strcmp(busqueda, "QUITA_DER") == 0) {
    cambios.pop_back();
}
```

---

Pero ya que has etiquetado la pregunta como C++, programa usando las herramientas del lenguaje:

```
std::string búsqueda; // NO uses char[10].
int valor;

for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {

    std::cin >> busqueda >> valor;

    if (busqueda == "AGREGA_IZQ") {
        cambios.push_front(valor);
    }
    else if (busqueda == "AGREGA_DER") {
        cambios.push_back(valor);
    }
    else if (busqueda == "QUITA_IZQ") {
        cambios.pop_front();
    }
    else if (busqueda == "QUITA_DER") {
        cambios.pop_back();
    }
}
```